# How to pass character strings to R from IML Studio

Tags: r, sas

If I define a function in IML:

```
start func(a);
  submit a / R;
   print(&a);
  endsubmit;
finish;
```

and run it:

```
run func("character string");
```

I get the error message: object 'character string' does not exist.

So R or IML is evaluating the character string into an object.  I want R to output "character string."  How do I do this?

Comment: Tip: next time use the button with binary numbers (or indent it with 4 spaces) to make the markdown engine interpret the code as code.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the new R/IML interface functionality, but from reading the help it looks like `submit foo` does text substitution. That is, if the IML variable `foo` contains the value `x`, then any occurrence of `&foo` in the submit block is replaced with `x`. When R is involved, IML generates R code to treat x as a symbol rather plain text. With that in mind, see if

```
start func(a);
  submit a / R;
    print("&a");
  endsubmit;
finish;
```

does what you want. Alternatively, you could use the ExportMatrixToR module to send the data to R:

```
start func(a);
   run ExportMatrixToR(a, "a");
   submit / R;
     print(a);
   endsubmit;
finish;
```

Caveat: untested code.

Comment: Hong's response is correct (and I tested that the code works). You almost surely want to use the ExportMatrixToR module (2nd method), because they the 'a' object in R is a real R object, and not just a literal.